# Calculated Member for Time Periods Hierarchy

Tags: ssas, mdx, hierarchy, olap

I need to create Calculated Member for "yesterday", "current month", "current year", but
but I keep getting an error message

please help me figure out why I'm getting the following error:

*"A set has been encountered that cannot contain calculated members."*

I have Attributes "Dates" and Hierarchies "Calendar" (YearID/QuarterId/MonthId/dtDate)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI0dn.png)

I created  Calculated Member "Current Month" for Parent hierarchy "Dates.Calendar.[all]"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TTY9.png)

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Dates].[Calendar].[All].[Current Month]

AS StrToMember("[Dates].[Calendar].[Month Id].&[" + Format(now(), "yyyyMM") + "]"),

VISIBLE = 1 ;
```

I'm getting an error

at the same time I built Named Set CurrentMonth and it works without problems

```
CREATE SET CURRENTCUBE.[CurrentMonth]

AS StrToMember("[Dates].[Calendar].[Month Id].&[" + Format(now(), "yyyyMM") + "]");
```

it's important to me that there is a Calculated Member and not a Named Set